# Pandas - Select row value from specific column based on value from other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is little convoluted, but I'll just show my data

I constructed following dataframe:

```
      Mid_XYZ  Mid_YYY  Mid_ZZZ Select1 Select2
867    1019.11   1027.64  1022.68   XYZ   YYY
873    1018.04   1027.58  1022.81   XYZ   ZZZ
```

I would want to select values from columns based on `Select1` and `Select2` strings by matching on part of a column name. In a first row, this would be

`1019.11` and `1027.64` (column `Mid_XYZ` and `Mid_YYY`) - because `Select1` has string `XYZ` and `Select2` has string `YYY`.

where, in a second row

`1018.04` and `1022.81` (column `Mid_XYZ` and `Mid_ZZZ`)

Later, I plan to store sum of those values in new column. DataFrame will look like this

```
      Mid_XYZ  Mid_YYY  Mid_ZZZ Select1 Select2 Sum
867    1019.11   1027.64  1022.68   XYZ   YYY   2046.75
873    1018.04   1027.58  1022.81   XYZ   ZZZ   2040.85
```

I can change column names to exact matching, but there should be some solution with regex? I know about `df.filter(regex='XYZ')`, but how can I do it row-wise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following vectorized solution:

```
import numpy as np

# clean rows
clean = df.columns.str.replace('^Mid_', '', regex=True)

# find matching column indices
s1 = np.argmax(clean.values == df['Select1'].values[:, None], axis=1)
s2 = np.argmax(clean.values == df['Select2'].values[:, None], axis=1)

# index and sum
df['Sum'] = df.values[np.arange(len(s1)), s1] + df.values[np.arange(len(s2)), s2]

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
     Mid_XYZ  Mid_YYY  Mid_ZZZ Select1 Select2      Sum
867  1019.11  1027.64  1022.68     XYZ     YYY  2046.75
873  1018.04  1027.58  1022.81     XYZ     ZZZ  2040.85
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
```

---

If you have:

```
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Mid_XYZ':[1019.11,1018.04],
                           'Mid_YYY':[1027.64,1027.58],
                           'Mid_ZZZ':[1022.68,1022.81],
                           'Select1':['XYZ','XYZ'],
                           'Select2':['YYY','ZZZ']})
```

You can do:

```
df['Sum']=df.apply(lambda row:
                   row['Mid_'+row['Select1']]+\
                   row['Mid_'+row['Select2']],
                   axis=1)
```

`df` will be:

```
   Mid_XYZ  Mid_YYY  Mid_ZZZ Select1 Select2      Sum
0  1019.11  1027.64  1022.68     XYZ     YYY  2046.75
1  1018.04  1027.58  1022.81     XYZ     ZZZ  2040.85
```

---

If you don't like `lambda` functions, can achieve the same result by defining a function:

```
def sumfunc(row):
    return row['Mid_'+row['Select1']]+row['Mid_'+row['Select2']]
```

Then:

```
df['Sum']=df.apply(sumfunc,axis=1)
```

Comment: this answer is good, but it isnt vectorized... voted up anyway :)

Comment: Thanks! I also voted up the vectorized answer. When I am having not incredibly large dataframes, I prefer readibility over vectorization, and I find this more solution more readable. Ofc, this is just an opinion :)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using `melt` and `concat`:

```
cols = ['Select1', 'Select2']
df1 = df.melt(id_vars=cols, ignore_index=False)
df['Sum'] = (pd.concat([df1[('Mid_' + df1[col]) == df1['variable']] 
                        for col in cols]).groupby(level=0).sum())  # can also pass `sort=False` to `groupby` for ~10% or something speed boost
df
Out[1]: 
     Mid_XYZ  Mid_YYY  Mid_ZZZ Select1 Select2      Sum
867  1019.11  1027.64  1022.68     XYZ     YYY  2046.75
873  1018.04  1027.58  1022.81     XYZ     ZZZ  2040.85
```

Answer (score 2):

in addition to @Dani Mesejo answer i added a little bit faster implementation and more strightforward using numpy built in where...

my implementation is `vec2` :

```
def vec1(df):
    clean = df.columns.str.replace('^Mid_', '', regex=True)
    s1 = np.argmax(clean.values == df['Select1'].values[:, None], axis=1)
    s2 = np.argmax(clean.values == df['Select2'].values[:, None], axis=1)
    # index and sum
    df['Sum'] = df.values[np.arange(len(s1)), s1] + df.values[np.arange(len(s2)), s2]
    return df

def vec2(df):
    clean = df.columns.str.replace('^Mid_', '', regex=True)
    idx1 = np.where(clean.values == df['Select1'].values[:,None] )
    idx2 = np.where(clean.values == df['Select2'].values[:,None] )
    df['Sum'] = df.values[idx1] + df.values[idx2]
    return df
```

here is timing comparisons:

my implementation:

```
%timeit vec2(df) : 388 µs ± 3.97 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

@Dani Mesejo :

```
%timeit vec1(df) : 405 µs ± 6.42 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```