# data frame per row select value from column based on value in row efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

The current set up of the problem is as follows:

| Run_or_swim | run_time | swim_time | time_care_about |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| run | 1.5 | 18 | 1.5 |
| swim | 2 | 22.2 | 22.2 |

How can I select the value to go into 'time_care_about' by variably selecting from the columns run_time and swim_time based on the value within run_or_swim in a efficient manner.

I'm not great at using Pandas so my current implementation of achieving creating the 'time_care_about' column is

```
df.apply(lambda x: x[f'{x['run_or_swim']}_time'],axis=1)
```

So per row it will check run_or_swim, to see if it is 'run' or 'swim', it will then look in the relevant column for the time and then we create the last column.
This is very slow as more columns are added, so is there a more efficient way of performing this? Or have I set up the problem poorly and abusing dataframes functionality.

e.g.
row 1

```
{x['run_or_swim']} = 'run'
f'{x['run_or_swim']}_time' = 'run_time'
x[f'{x['run_or_swim']}_time'] = x['run_time'] = 1.5
```

The example extends to ~8 columns this needs to be done for
e.g. run_distance, swim_distance,
run_elevation, swim_elevation

Using the suggestions below suggestions actually caused the time to be slower?
[Pandas - Select row value from specific column based on value from other columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65568003/pandas-select-row-value-from-specific-column-based-on-value-from-other-columns)

Thanks for any suggestions or links to relevant posts!

---

By request (and my mistake) extending the problem description:

| Run_or_swim | run_time | swim_time | time_care_about | run_distance | swim_distance | distance_care_about |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| run | 1.5 | 18 | 1.5 | 123 | 789 | 123 |
| swim | 2 | 22.2 | 22.2 | 543 | 1111 | 1111 |

For this example where iterating over multiple metrics ~ 500 in my use case , apply ends up performing faster than broadcasting.
apply ~ 1.12s
broadcasting ~ 1.45s

The set up I then use is:

```
for metric in [metric list]:
   df.apply(lambda x: x[f'{x['run_or_swim']}_{metric}'],axis=1)
```

and

```
for metric in [metric_list]:
   col_idx = (df.columns.to_numpy() == df[f"Run_or_swim"].add(
                        f'_{metric}').to_numpy()[:, None]).argmax(axis=1)
                    
 
 
    df[f"{metric}_care_about"] =df.values[df.index, col_idx]
```

Is it also possible to broadcast over the list of metrics?

Comment: *"extends to ~8 columns"* - can you post that fragment with multiple final columns?

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy and broadcasting:

```
col_idx = (df.columns.to_numpy() == df['Run_or_swim'].add('_time').to_numpy()[:, None]).argmax(axis=1)

df['time_care_about'] = df.values[df.index, col_idx]
print(df)

# Output
  Run_or_swim  run_time  swim_time time_care_about
0         run       1.5       18.0             1.5
1        swim       2.0       22.2            22.2
```

Comment: I prefer indexing lookup, but numpy is definitely the way to go :)

Comment: Hi thanks for the clear comment!
I just tried this suggestion and its an improvement on another method I was trying, however it still performs slower than apply when looped over multiple metrics. I've edited the question accordingly, do you have any further suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Using a variation of the [indexing lookup](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-lookup):

```
idx, cols = pd.factorize(df['Run_or_swim']+'_time')

df['time_care_about'] = (df.reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()
                         [np.arange(len(df)), idx]
                         )
```

Variant removing `_time` for the original columns:

```
idx, cols = pd.factorize(df['Run_or_swim'])

df['time_care_about'] = (df.set_axis(df.columns.str.removesuffix('_time'), axis=1)
                           .reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()
                         [np.arange(len(df)), idx]
                        )
```

Output:

```
  Run_or_swim  run_time  swim_time  time_care_about
0         run       1.5       18.0              1.5
1        swim       2.0       22.2             22.2
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I could test, your solution is not that bad I did some tests, and here are 3 other options tested on a random generated data frame with 10000 rows:

The test 0 was using your solution:

```
Test 0
time_0:  0.109017849
```

The test 1 was with a loop:

```py
df1['time_care_about'] = np.nan
for i in range(len(df1)):
    if df1['run_or_swim'][i] == 'run':
        df1['time_care_about'][i] = df1['run_time'][i]
    else:
        df1['time_care_about'][i] = df1['swim_time'][i]
# time_1:  2.9705018997
```

As expected very slow compared to the first option.

The other approach is still slower than yours with `0.1215393543s` that is using list comprehension:

```py
df2['time_care_about'] = [df2['run_time'][i] if df2['run_or_swim'][i] == 'run' else df2['swim_time'][i] for i in range(len(df2))]
```

Last the faster approach by far was using numpy `where` statement:

```py
df3['time_care_about'] = np.where(df3['run_or_swim'] == 'run', df3['run_time'], df3['swim_time'])
```

With a time of `0.0020861626s`